# Perfect move command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, move

Is there a command in CMD/PowerShell to perform a "perfect" cut-paste, where the command only copy file to target when he can delete the source?

Because all my attempts with `robocopy` and `move` weren't successful as it was a cut-paste for movable files and a copy-past for non-movable files, so it was difficult to store that many files on a same drive, because it needs nearly double the space with this method. And in final, I don't want the files that can't be moved, only the one that can be

Comment: have you determined why the unmovable files cannot be moved?

Comment: I haven't considering that it's multiple reasons depending on the file, and it's location. And it's totally okay, as I don't want to get the unmovable files. I want to skip them to just get the movable ones

Comment: well, alot of the reasons a file can't be moved can't be established until the file has already been copied and it attempts to delete the original. note that there is no difference between a copy followed by a delete, and a cut/move, other than that if the destination is on the same partition, a copy will actually write new data for the file, while a move will just update the filesystem metadata. if the destination is on a different partition, there is no real difference. so as a result, you will need to exclude those files from the copy, and that involves determining what files won't delete.

Comment: My move technique is extremely slow and massive considering that it takes a tremendous time to create a new file. But considering that I only want to move on the same partition, the operation could be near instantaneous if I just had to update fs metadata, and that's what I want. But I personally have no way to determine which file is moveable. I need something that will only be able to update, not create. So it will not begin a useless operation and create a dupe

Comment: Or maybe even something that test deletable data to create a list to effectively move. Or at least, if it's too difficult, I need something that will perform the long copies, but if it can't delete the source, it deletes the target. So it will be long but at least not uselessly big

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsReadOnly` property to filter read-only items out before moving:

```
> Get-ChildItem | 
    Where-Object {-not $_.IsReadOnly} | 
      Move-Item -Destination destfolder
```

Comment: Until now I was using the command `robocopy $source $target /xd $target /s /dcopy:dat /copy:dat /move /j /nooffload /mt:128 /r:0 /w:0 /log:$target\logs`. I will have to tinker with PSH to get those functions in this new command